# IntelliJ IDEA can't find KoaJS methods

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, koa2

Currently, IntelliJ IDEA reports that KoaJS's methods are undefined.

[image]

Does anyone use intellij idea with KoaJS and have intellisense/code completion working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Koa methods resolved, please try using Koa typescript stubs: download  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types/koa/koa.d.ts file and set it up as a JavaScript Library (`Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`, `Add...`)